# How do I vertically align placeholder for an input element on UC browser Mobile?

Tags: css, mobile, cross-browser

My question is browser specific. My css doesn't work in UC Browser on mobile as fine as it works in other browsers.

I want to align the placeholder vertically in the center. But to my surprise the vertical alignment seems to be a little off.

Here's the screenshot I took from the UC browser
[image]

Here's the link to my fiddle [Open in UC browser](http://jsfiddle.net/rickieanand/9kq1e1b0/show)

Here's the link to UC browser: [UC Browser Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.UCMobile.intl&hl=en)

[UC Browser for Ios](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/uc-browser-fast-browsing-powerful-ad-block/id1048518592?mt=8)

I have applied the following css

```css
.date-input {     
    padding: 8px 30px 8px 36px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 19px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="date-input" placeholder="Hello World">
```

Kindly help

Comment: I think you can adjust it using padding.

Comment: @athimohan I checked it for the facebook website on the UC browser and it shows the same for the login input text field. :(

Comment: Try and set your line-height using `em` units.

Answer (score 1):

Just use em instead of pixels...

```
.date-input {     
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.35em;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0.57em;
}
```

Comment: I hope it helped you my friend :-)